# Cannot open storyboard after update to os x mavericks ASSERTION FAILURE

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Application Specific Information:
Sending _openAs: to  from 
ProductBuildVersion: 5A2053
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3746/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint, IBUIButton, IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUISwitch, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: containingTableView
Reason:     Any table view cell being added to a layout engine should be contained in a table view in order to get the correct metrics
File:       /SourceCache/IBSimulatorComponents/IBSimulatorComponents-3649/IBCocoaTouchTool/WidgetIntegration/IBUITableViewCellIntegration.m:219
Method:     -[UITableViewCell(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) ibEffectiveViewToPlaceInLayoutEngineWindow]

After updating to os x mavericks...This exception appears when i try to open my storyboard in Xcode 5. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you install the new Xcode 5? If not do so.

Comment: i installed updates to Xcode too

Comment: Did you do a Project Clean, if that doesn't help, then removed the Derived folder for the project, quit Xcode, restart, try again? Did you do a Disk Utility disk verify, permissions fix etc too? I'm having my own problems with Mavericks right now...

Comment: nothings helps(
Any table view cell being added to a layout engine should be contained in a table view in order to get the correct metrics

the problem is like this but storyboard crashes even when i try to edit it

Comment: @DavidH thanks! I know this is almost 3 years after your comment but I completely forgot to try something as simple as that for a similar problem and your suggestion worked :-)

Comment: Whelp, never mind. Just came back and I don't know why :-(

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem in XCode 6+ recently. This problem in my case was caused because I copied a tableview section by mistake into a split view controller and didn't notice. This didn't cause XCode to crash at that moment and didn't cause a problem till the next startup.

**If you can't even open your project because XCode tries to open the storyboard containing this issue on startup, try this:**
To fix this I had to delete all user-data files contained in the project folder and in the project workspace folder (you can view these files by right clicking the project file and selecting "Show Package Contents"). Basicly just delete all folders that have the name xcuserdata or xcshareddata contained in the project. Now you should be able to open the project again.

**If Xcode crashes when you try to view the storyboard giving the error mentioned above:**
The first thing I did was I right clicked on the storyboard (don't left click it first or it will crash again!) and select "Open As -> Source Code". Then I searched for the tag "tableViewCell" and looked for the cells that weren't contained in a tableview element. Then you simply delete the incorrect xml elements and subelements (in my case a whole tableviewsection), save it and your good to go again (hopefully).

Hope this helps anyone else getting this issue.

Comment: After only opening my storyboard in source code mode and coming back to interface builder, Xcode crashed. Tried to change back the storyboard from (All All) to (C R) that I was working... Xcode kept crashing. After some minutes of despair, I followed your advice (second one); deleted the wrong tableViewCell  and IT WORKED. You saved my life! You're a true super hero! Lol Thank you, mate